# How to retrieve specific elements from a 2 dimensional tensorflow array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I have a tensor which is of shape (4,2)

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(4, 2), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3],
       [4, 5],
       [6, 7]])>
```

If I were to acess only select elements from the tensor, ex 1,2,5,6 how would i do so, lets say i have 2 lists or numpy arrays M = [0,1,2,3] AND N=[1,0,1,0] to specify the elements how do i access them, if it was a numpy array just array[M,N] works fine  but in tensorflow it says that :

```
Only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), tf.newaxis (`None`) and scalar tf.int32/tf.int64 tensors are valid indices, got array
```

is there a specific way to do so!?

Answer (score 0):

Use `gather_nd()`:

```
a = tf.constant([[0, 1],
       [2, 3],
       [4, 5],
       [6, 7]])
M = [0,1,2,3]
N = [1,0,1,0]

inds = tf.stack((M, N))
inds = tf.transpose(inds)
res = tf.gather_nd(a, inds)
```